# Exporting a JavaFX multi-class Eclipse project – Desktop run makes no effect

Tags: eclipse, javafx, jar, export

I am actively and as so far unsuccessfully looking for a way to **export a JavaFX multi-class application** in Eclipse.

Following steps were already tried:

1. Export of **Runnable Jar** file (in all of three modes: Extract, Package and Copy libraries);
2. Export of **Jar** file, where I tried to set my main application class as entry point class in Manifest file specification, I tried this as I guessed maybe it is necessary in my case the same as it is with exporting of console runnable projects;
3. **Command-line compiling** of my application’s main class which failed with **‘cannot find symbol’** errors.

The app has one stage, two packages and several scenes each one in separate class, connected by inheritance. In past I already **successfully exported** projects in Eclipse, they also had graphic elements and also consisted of two packages but contrary to the present project were **single-class apps**.

I have read attentively all the posts here regarding Eclipse exports, even saw the ones describing the situation similar to mine where **projects went ok in Eclipse but did not start from Desktop.** But my problem is particular because it is about an application with multiple classes and as stated above, short one-class Eclipse projects posed me no problem with exporting and subsequent running.

The presence of many classes could in my opinion be behind my problem, but I have no clue of what to change and why the App runs in Eclipse and does not on desktop. In practice, when double clicked on desktop, the application does not run nor gives any error notification.

I avoid posting here up to one thousand lines of code, nevertheless, I can publish it if anyone asks me to.

Happy New Year 2016 to all and thanks for each reading and commenting of this post.

Here-below some illustrative **screenshots**:

1. Project’s structure
   [image]
2. Runnable JAR file
   [image]
3. All three modes were tried:
   [image]
4. JAR file
   [image]
5. Jar file Intermediate export page
   [image]
6. Packaging options
   [image]
7. Manifest export project specification
   [image]
8. Here are the messages I get when running my Eclipse exported application from command line
   [image]

Comment: Is there an error if you run it from the command line?

Comment: Command line gives 3 kinds of errors: **1** - invalid or corrupted jarfile when I launch the main application class; **2** - could not find or load main class when run the whole exported application with 'java appname.jar' and finally **3** - a huge list of errors when I run the app with 'java -jar appname.jar and whose reason is totally unknown to me. I will update the post to display this with a screenshot.

Comment: How do you invoke the `Image` constructor (in `Main.start` (line 65)). Have you checked, if the jar contains the image?

Answer (score 0):

Question is resolved and the situation turned out be exceptionally trivial:

The format of my graphic element used in the application was in **capital letters** which prevented compiler from doing its job.

All this is visible on my first screen named 'Project's structure'

**Thanks to Fabian** for bringing up the idea of possible problem with the image, it helped me to get to the right place where to search for the bug.

PS for **moderators: I did not post the question to get fun** by asking a question and answering it myself, at the moment I honestly had not idea on how to resolve my problem but spotted the solution 1 hour later

Comment: You don't need the PS remark, [self-answering questions is encouraged on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).